# MVC HtmlHelper BeginForm rendering differently with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, html-helper

So within a fairly large application I have a view for "Product1" with a form using an HtmlHelper.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ...etc
}
```

This renders to:

```
<form action="/Products/Product1?__RequestVerificationToken=PYs...
...
</form>
```

And this works great.

However, if I change it to (or anything similar to)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {onsubmit = "return validationCheck()"}))
...etc
```

It renders to

```
<form action="/Login?action=Product1&controller=Products" method="post" onsubmit="return validationCheck()">
```

**Any** parameters passed into BeginForm forces it back to the login screen. I was of the understanding that inputting nulls was the same as using the default values. I have tried many combinations of parameters for BeginForm(), all of them send me to my login screen.

I know there is limited information here (sorry), but I'm looking for a reason of why it renders differently. With default parameters I would assume it should render exactly the same as without any parameters.

All I actually want to work is the validationCheck, so if you have a workaround that can do that I'd be keen to hear that too.

Comment: Better to use [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) than polluting your presentation with behavior. `@using (Html.BeginForm())` and `$('form').submit(function(e) { // validate });`

Comment: That worked! Still don't understand why it renders differently, but your answer isn't just a workaround, it's a _better_ solution. Thanks.

If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted, else I'll answer it myself.

Comment: The reason I added a comment and not an answer is because I didn't believe you claim. I have now tested this numerous times and cannot reproduce your results - it always renders the form tag correctly using your second `BeginForm` implementation so there is something else going on in your code that's causing the `action` attribute to be rendered incorrectly. Possibly something to do with your route table?

Comment: This is new MVC5 pages in an existing ASP.NET webforms project. There's a lot of stuff going on which would be too long to post here, and obviously I won't post all of the companies auth code here. The strangest thing for me is that the 2 render differently. I was hoping someone might have come across this before, or have an idea what it could be but I guess if I want to find out now I'd have to go look at the `BeginForm()` source code. However, this would be purely academic now as it's working as it needs to.